# How to create PySpark job as a Web Service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have few PySpark jobs runs on EMR and i would like create them as a web service.   Any guidance or help in this case or any other better approach ?

Thanks.

Comment: Started looking into this, if any updates i'll post here.

Comment: Sparkjob-server : REST job server for Apache Spark https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: Whether the above link supports PySpark and YARN as well ? Because i'm seeing all scala code only.

Answer (score 0):

As of now using "Amazon API Gateway" to achieve above my requirement.